# Conflicts after git reset --hard

Tags: git

I've got a branch named `master` and I want to reset **all** changes made on this branch. Need to move all commits from branch named `origin/d` to `master`. 
So this is what I did (on branch `master`):

```
git fetch -all
git reset --hard origin/d
git clean -f -d
git push origin master --force
```

I've got following message:

```
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)
```

But I don't want to pull, I just want move all commits from branch `d` to branch `master` (ignoring all local/non-local commits on branch `master`).

When I put `git pull` I've got many conflicts that I do not want to resolve. Could anyone help me and tell me what is the simplest way to do that?

Comment: That error seems to indicate that the server is disallowing your `--force` argument. What are you running on the server? Is it self-hosted?

Comment: The `m` branch is exactly `master` branch so this is the case of error.

Comment: What server are you running? Do you have admin access?

Comment: I do not have admin access

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message indicates that (1) your server is disallowing forced updates (the `--force` argument), and (2) for some reason Git wants to push `m` to `master`.

To temporarily work around the second issue, you can do:

```
git push origin m:refs/heads/m --force-with-lease
```

(It's better to use `--force-with-lease` rather than `--force`, because the former will only overwrite if your remote-tracking branch is up-to-date. If someone else happened to push commits since you last `fetch`ed, then `--force` will overwrite those, causing work to be lost.)

However, if your server is disallowing forced updates, then it will probably reject that command as well. If you have admin access to your server, then one option is to change that. Otherwise, to work around that, you should be able to delete the branch and then push:

```
git push origin --delete m
git push origin m:refs/heads/m
```

If that doesn't work, then you'll have to contact your server administrator and ask them to allow you to delete branches and/or to force-update them.

Comment: The m branch is the master exactly. When I use git pull, the git will merge some  changes from old m branch I supposed, and there will some conflicts and some modified files that I do not want to. Is there any possibility to just move all commits (and nothing more) from d branch to m branch? how to resolved all conflicts as mine (from d branch) and prevent to modified other files from d branch as a result of merge?

Comment: @user2921643 Okay, that explains the second issue. Please [edit](//stackoverflow.com/help/editing) this additional information into your question. While you're at it, please answer the question I asked in my comment on your question.

Comment: Changed `m` to `master`

Answer (score 4):

Yeap you give this error cause you don't have latest changes from repository, so you should pull them.

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git pull --rebase // fetch and pull together
```

and after resolving conflicts (if they will exist) you will can doing push

```
git push origin master
```